# How to unit-test an abstract class, when its constructor executes its abstract method(-s)?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit, abstract-class

I'm writing `PHPUnit` unit tests for this `Zend Framework 2` class:

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\InputFilter;

use Zend\InputFilter\Input as ZendInput;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputInterface;
use MyNamespace\Exception\InvalidParameterException;

abstract class AbstractInput extends ZendInput
{
    final public function __construct()
    {
        // The constructor uses/executes the abstract method getInputSpecification().
        $this->init($this->getInputSpecification());
    }
    public function merge(InputInterface $input)
    {
        $mergedInput = parent::merge($input);
        $mergedInput->setFallbackValue($input->getFallbackValue());
        return $mergedInput;
    }
    public function isValid()
    {
        $this->injectNotEmptyValidator();
        $validator = $this->getValidatorChain();
        $value     = $this->getValue();
        $result    = $validator->isValid($value, $context);
        return $result;
    }
    protected function init($inputSpecification)
    {
        $factory = new Factory();
        $tempInput = $factory->createInput($inputSpecification);
        $this->merge($tempInput);
    }
    abstract protected function getInputSpecification();
    public function getFinalValue($param)
    {
        $finalValue = null;
        if (empty($param) || $this->getValue() === '') {
            if ($this->getFallbackValue() !== null) {
                $finalValue = $this->getFallbackValue();
            } else {
                throw new InvalidParameterException('The parameter ' . $this->name . ' must be set!');
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->isValid()) {
                $finalValue = $this->getValue();
            } else {
                throw new InvalidParameterException('The parameter ' . $this->name . ' is invalid!');
            }
        }
        return $finalValue;
    }
}
```

and get a problem with this. This code

```
// ...
class AbstractInputTest extends TestCase
{
    // ...
    public function setUp()
    {
        $stub = $this->getMockForAbstractClass('\MyNamespace\InputFilter\AbstractInput');
        $stub
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getInputSpecification')
            ->will($this->returnValue(array())
        );
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

causes an error:

> $ phpunit SgtrTest/InputFilter/AbstractInputTest.php PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Configuration read from /path/to/project/tests/phpunit.xml
>
> E...
>
> Time: 1 second, Memory: 7,00Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) **SgtrTest\InputFilter\AbstractInputTest::testMerge
>   Zend\InputFilter\Exception\InvalidArgumentException:
>   Zend\InputFilter\Factory::createInput expects an array or Traversable;
>   received "NULL"**
>
> /path/to/project/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/InputFilter/Factory.php:98
>   /path/to/project/vendor/SGTR/library/MyNamespace/InputFilter/AbstractInput.php:72
>   /path/to/project/vendor/SGTR/library/MyNamespace/InputFilter/AbstractInput.php:31
>   /path/to/project/tests/SgtrTest/InputFilter/AbstractInputTest.php:20
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 4, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

I undestand, why the error is thrown. Bu how to to resolve this in another way?

Comment: Unit test the concrete classes that extend your abstract.... not that it's a class with abstract methods, not an abstract class

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But should one not unit test abstract classes? OK, abstract classes contains also concrete methods -- and they should be tested -- directly in the test classes of the class, not in the test classes of subclasses. E.g. [`ZendTest\Cache\Storage\Adapter\AbstractAdapter`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/tests/ZendTest/Cache/Storage/Adapter/AbstractAdapterTest.php)

Answer (score 1):

In my test, I create a quick class extending the abstract class, then I test the concrete methods in that class.

```
class TestAbstractInput extends AbstractInput
{
    ...
}

class AbstractInputTest extends TestCase
{
    // ...
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->TestClassObject = new TestAbstractInput();
    }

    public function test_isValid()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->TestClassObject->isValid);
    }
}
```

After this, you can then use the either a Mock object of the Abstract class created in the test, or mock the Abstract class as you have done.

Comment: I think, that a good workaround. Have to try it out. Thank you!

Comment: Did this work for you?  If so, can you accept the answer for others to see, or can I help by providing more information?